# How can I get an embedded Vine video to scale dynamically to different devices?

Tags: html, iframe, video, scaling, vine

I'm trying to embed a vine video in a wordpress page and am having a hard time getting the video to scale when viewed on an iPhone. I haven't really had any luck adding things to the embed code html wise. But that's probably because I'm a total noob.

Here is the code I'd like to have dynamically scale.

```
<iframe class="vine-embed" src="https://vine.co/v/bVuUeLXBHBF/embed/simple" 
width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script async 
src="//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to post the code?

```
<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/bnrtW52x1uJ/card?mute=1"
width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If that is vine embed code, can you just change width/height to percentages if you are currently using pixels?

Comment: Thanks... still learning how to use this.

I tried the "100%" tip and it didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Are you using or have you checked out the "vine-embed" class in your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking today for an answer..and this worked for me:

Style

```
.embed-container {
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 100%; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow:  hidden;
} 
.embed-container iframe, 
.embed-container object, 
.embed-container embed {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='embed-container'>
    <iframe width='100%' src='https://vine.co/v/h9eAhKWzJlv/embed/simple' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
    <script async src='//platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same infuriating problem, when my site needed to be responsive. Fiddling with width and height attributes and the styling did nothing for me. I ended up writing a function to calculate the width and height I needed on page load, then writing the iframe into the innerHTML of the contain div element:

```
function setVineDimensions () {
    var dimension = document.getElementById('vine_container').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById('vine_container').innerHTML  = '<iframe class="vine-embed" src="https://vine.co/v/XXXXXXXX/embed/simple" width="' + dimension + '" height="' + dimension + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
}

setVineDimensions();
```

Note that the above is just the iframe. When you grab the embed code from Vine there is a script as well. Pop that up in the header and you're good to go.

This solution works only on a page load/refresh. If you're prone to resizing your browser window it won't change.